# dmvnorm command in R

Tags: r, determinants

I am working with two 128x128 dimensional matrices in R. I want to clarify if the actual determinant of these matrices is actually infinite as thrown out by R or it is just a computational limit.

```
> det(sigma_1)
[1] 4.836624e+166
> det(sigma_2)
[1] Inf
```

I obtain these matrices in successive iterations. So, it is difficult for me to belive that determinant of matrix actually blows up to Infinity

Is there a way to check if it is just that R is unable to handle high-dimensional determinant?

The reproducible example is on the workspace saved [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sXOZxM0tDNToRpsIuFX9jji0JN5mEsQQ) and loaded from here.

Comment: A singular matrix A has determinant det A = 0 (not infinity); this looks more like a floating point precision issue involving very large numbers, leading to numerical instability. It is usually recommended to include a minimal & reproducible example including sample data rather than a link to your complete workspace. Could you please edit your question to include those details?

Comment: @MauritsEvers: Thank you for the feedback. Actually, I was indeed trying to get a minimum reproducbile example. Unfortunately, this error happens only after a few iterations in my code. So, I could not include a minimal reproducible example in this case. Any suggestions on how to provide a minimum reproducible example in this case is welcome.